# Loading indicator is not animating

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to implement a button in SwiftUI that will show a loading indicator on click. but after the button click, the loading indicator is not animating.

```swift
{
    Button(action: {
        self.isLoading = true
    }) {
        HStack {
            if isLoading {
                Circle()
                    .trim(from: 0, to: 0.7)
                    .stroke(Color.green, lineWidth: 5)
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                    .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: isLoading ? 360 : 0))
                    .animation(.default
                                .repeatForever(autoreverses: false), value: isLoading)
            }
                Text( isLoading ? "Processing" : "Submit")
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .font(.title)
            }
    }
    .frame(width: 250, height: 50)
    .background(.white)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be different states: one for transition, one for progress. So it is better to separate progress into different view

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

Note: it's better to use `linear` animation in this case

[image: demo]

```
HStack {
    if isLoading {
        MyProgress()   // << here !!
    }
        Text( isLoading ? "Processing" : "Submit")
            .fontWeight(.semibold)
            .font(.title)
    }
```

and

```
struct MyProgress: View {
    @State var isLoading = false
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .trim(from: 0, to: 0.7)
            .stroke(Color.green, lineWidth: 5)
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: isLoading ? 360 : 0))
            .animation(.linear
                        .repeatForever(autoreverses: false), value: isLoading)
            .onAppear {
                isLoading = true
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Asperi, for the quick response.
I want to understand what was wrong with my implementation and why the animation is not working (in my implementation)

Comment: @AlokChandra, your implementation doesn't work because animation needs to be based upon two different states.  The first time the circle appears on screen in your implementation, it has rotation 360.  At no time does the circle appear with rotation 0, so there is nothing to animate since SwiftUI sees no change.